# How to create a script with Automator to watermark each PDF in a folder with a different watermark?

Tags: macos, applescript, bash, automator, pdf

I am trying to create a script to watermark a group a PDF files in a folder, each PDF has to have a unique watermark.

All the PDFs are in one folder, all the watermarks are in .png located in another folder.
I currently have watermark script which I found on Apple Forums, but this was made to watermark all files with one watermark only.

What I need is a way to watermark each PDF file with it's own different watermark (there are 400 pdfs and 400 different watermarks)

[image: Automator Screenshot]

Here is the contents of the watermark `tool.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Watermark each page in a PDF document

import sys #, os
import getopt
import math
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *
from Quartz.ImageIO import *

def drawWatermark(ctx, image, xOffset, yOffset, angle, scale, opacity):
    if image:
        imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image)
        imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image)
        imageBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)
        
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
        CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, opacity)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, xOffset, yOffset)
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, scale)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2)
        CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angle * math.pi / 180)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -imageWidth / 2, -imageHeight / 2)
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageBox, image)
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)

def createImage(imagePath):
    image = None
    
    # provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(imagePath)    # FIXED: replaced by the following CGDataProviderCreateWithURL()
    url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, imagePath, len(imagePath), False)
    provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL(url)
    
    if provider:
        imageSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, None)
        if imageSrc:
            image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSrc, 0, None)
    if not image:
        print "Cannot import the image from file %s" % imagePath
    return image

def watermark(inputFile, watermarkFiles, outputFile, under, xOffset, yOffset, angle, scale, opacity, verbose):
    
    images = map(createImage, watermarkFiles)
    
    ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, outputFile, len(outputFile), False), None, None)
    if ctx:
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, inputFile, len(inputFile), False))
        if pdf:
            
            for i in range(1, CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf) + 1):
                image = images[i % len(images) - 1]
                page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i)
                if page:
                    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)
                    if CGRectIsEmpty(mediaBox):
                        mediaBox = None
                    
                    CGContextBeginPage(ctx, mediaBox)
                    if under:
                        drawWatermark(ctx, image, xOffset, yOffset, angle, scale, opacity)
                    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page)
                    if not under:
                        drawWatermark(ctx, image, xOffset, yOffset, angle, scale, opacity)
                    CGContextEndPage(ctx)
    
        del pdf
        CGPDFContextClose(ctx)
    del ctx

def main(argv):
    
    verbose = False
    readFilename = None
    writeFilename = None
    under = False
    xOffset = 0.0   # FIXED: changed to float value
    yOffset = 0.0   # FIXED: changed to float value
    angle = 0.0     # FIXED: changed to float value
    scale = 1.0     # FIXED: added
    opacity = 1.0
    
    # Parse the command line options
    try:
        options, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "vutx:y:a:p:s:i:o:", ["verbose", "under", "over", "xOffset=", "yOffset=", "angle=", "opacity=", "scale=", "input=", "output=", ])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    for option, arg in options:
        
        print option, arg
        
        if option in ("-i", "--input") :
            if verbose:
                print "Reading pages from %s." % (arg)
            readFilename = arg
        
        elif option in ("-o", "--output") :
            if verbose:
                print "Setting %s as the output." % (arg)
            writeFilename = arg
        
        elif option in ("-v", "--verbose") :
            print "Verbose mode enabled."
            verbose = True
        
        elif option in ("-u", "--under"):
            print "watermark under PDF"
            under = True
        
        elif option in ("-t", "--over"):    # FIXED: changed to "-t" from "t"
            print "watermark over PDF"
            under = False
        
        elif option in ("-x", "--xOffset"):
            xOffset = float(arg)
        
        elif option in ("-y", "--yOffset"):
            yOffset = float(arg)
        
        elif option in ("-a", "--angle"):
            angle = -float(arg)
        
        elif option in ("-s", "--scale"):
            scale = float(arg)
        
        elif option in ("-p", "--opacity"):
            opacity = float(arg)
        
        else:
            print "Unknown argument: %s" % (option)

    if (len(args) > 0):
        watermark(readFilename, args, writeFilename, under, xOffset, yOffset, angle, scale, opacity, verbose);
    else:
        shutil.copyfile(readFilename, writeFilename);

def usage():
    print "Usage: watermark --input <file> --output <file> <watermark files>..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: A few questions...how are you associating the watermark file with the PDF file?  Do you need to watermark each page of the PDF or just the first page?  Where does this watermark have to be placed?

Comment: Each PDF has only one page, each watermark has to be placed on the center of the page.

Usually, I can achieve this by doing the watermarks one by one. But doing this for 400 files takes a considerable amount of time.

The problem is that the watermark scripts were written to use only one watermark for multiple files, or for one PDF file with multiple pages.

Comment: Do the watermark image files and the corresponding image files have the same name ( for e.g. 1.png for 1.pdf etc.)?

Comment: Yes they all have corresponding names, I put the files in two different folders.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this under **macOS Catalina** using the *code* from the `tool.py` in the OP and the *value* of the *options* shown for it, while using **PDF** *documents* and *graphic image files* for the *watermark*, where the *files* are in different locations. It works for me as coded.

The following *example* **shell script** *code* assumes that for each **PDF** *document* there is a corresponding *graphic image file* of the same *name* with a different *extension* with all watermark *files* being in a different *directory*.

You will need to set the *value* of three *variables* at the top of the *script*, `p2wf`, `wext` and `fqp2pyf`, while the rest of the *values* from the original *script* are maintained except where they have already been modified.

In the **Automator** *workflow*, using a **Get Specified Finder Items** *action* for the **PDF** *documents* and a **Run Shell Script** *action* set as shown in your OP:

- **Shell: [/bin/bash]**
- **Pass input: [as arguments]**

Replace any existing *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action*, default or otherwise, with:

```bash
    # Path to watermark files.
    # Example: "${HOME}/Pictures/Watermarks"
    # Watermark file extension, e.g.: png
    # Fully qualified pathname to python 'tool.py' file.
    # Example: "${HOME}/bin/tool.py"

p2wf="${HOME}/Pictures/Watermarks"
wext="png"
fqp2pyf="${HOME}/bin/tool.py"


    # f = fully qualified pathname
    # d = directory pathname
    # fn = filename with extension
    # n = filename without extension
    # e = filename extension

for f in "$@"; do

    d="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    n="${fn%.*}"
    e="${fn##*.}"

    "${fqp2pyf}" \
    --over \
    --xOffset 56 \
    --yOffset 58 \
    --angle 0 \
    --scale 0.11 \
    --opacity 1 \
    --input "${f}" \
    --output "${d}/${n} (COPY).${e}" \
    "${p2wf}/${n}.${wext}"

done
```

---

<sup>**Note:** From past experience, I never use `~` for the home directory in *scripts*. I use e.g., `$HOME` or `${HOME}` as `~` can actually be problematic in some situations.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! 
Will try the code you sugested.

Comment: @Lauro Mota, Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)